# Can't set canvas image with relative path

Tags: reactjs

I have a canvas and I want it to have a default image when the page loads. Here's how my component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/canvas.css';

function Canvas() {

    window.onload = () => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = '../photos/PNGbackground.png';
        img.onload = function () { 
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="canvContainer">
                <canvas className="canv" id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Canvas;
```

My problem is that the image doesn't appear on the canvas. I also tried to give the path this way:

```
img.src = window.location.href + 'src/photos/PNGbackground.png';
```

which gives me this path when I console.log the `img`

```
src="http://localhost:3000/src/photos/PNGbackground.png"
```

But the image still doesn't appear. Here is the structure of src my folder:

- photos

  - PNGbackground.png
- Canvas.js

How can I fix this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: `img.src = require(../photos/PNGbackground.png)`

Comment: BTW when you have a React project, why do you use the vanilla JS/HTML approach? You have lifecycle at hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import image

```
import PNGbackground from '../yourpath/src/photos/PNGbackground.png'; //Please be careful about image path It should be correct as per your image directory.
```

then use PNGbackground as like below

```
img.src = PNGbackground;
```